# Can I use Log4cplus AsyncAppender on a self implemented appender-inheriting class?

Tags: asynchronous, syslog, log4cplus

I have implemented Appender inheriting class in Log4cplus, which on the Append() function- opens a TCP socket and sends the event log message to a remote server, and I am wondering:

Can I make this self-implemented appender an asynchronous appender by wrapping the AsyncAppender around it 
(as also described here: [Is Log4cplus RollingFileAppender Asynchronous or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699956/is-log4cplus-rollingfileappender-asynchronous-or-not) )?

I also wonder: is the Log4cplus SyslogAppender can also become an asynchronous appender by wrapping the AsyncAppender around it the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any appender instance with `AsyncAppender`. Also, if you are using log4cplus 2.x, you can make any appender asynchronous by setting `AsyncAppend` property to `true` on it. In either case there is a queue that is being consumed by thread(s) that call basically call `append()`.

Comment: And when using AsyncAppender,  does the order of log events writing is kept? Is there maybe some sort of a queue that keeps events order?

Comment: Hi wilx, Is there a way to set/configure this queue size? I see the default queue is limited to length of 100. can I enlarge the queue?

Comment: @N.avraham: There is `QueueLimit` property that you can set.

Comment: Hi wilx, What exactly happens in case the Queue is full? are events lost? and if yes- then are the older or the newer ones are to be lost?

Comment: @N.avraham `AsyncAppender` queue blocks on a semaphore if it is full.